# Sound not working in Ubuntu 22.04.01 and also not in Windows if coming from Ubuntu

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

This afternoon I suspended my laptop on **Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS** after stopping a video. When I opened it hours later, sound on Ubuntu was just not working. It detects the speakers, settings say they are reproducing sound (via the graphical interface, when I play something in the background) but nothing can be heard.

When I restarted and entered **Windows 10**, the speakers started making this loud bop sound every second, perfectly timed. It stopped and restarted when I tried playing something with audio. I later on turned off the PC, and when I entered Windows after shutting down, everything was alright. However, changing back to Ubuntu 22.04.01, the loop restarted: no sound, then no sound on windows, turn off, and working on windows but not on Ubuntu 22.04.01.

(P.S.: I tried detecting the devices and changing stuff with pulseaudio and alsa and nothing worked, even reinstalling those)

Can anyone check this out?

(EDIT: After **shutting down** the laptop, every OS I boot has working sound. If just **reboot** it and swap from one OS to the other, then it doesn't work - in any)

Thank you!

Comment: I have corrected it: *Ubuntu 22.04.01 indeed :)

Comment: Update UEFI and, as always when dual-booting with Windows, disable its (Windows) Fast Startup feature.